# Kafka Connect Deserializing byte array

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to receive byte array serialized Avro messages with help of Kafka connect. 
Producer configuration for serializing avro data

```
key.serializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
value.serializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

hdfs sink configuration

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=csvtopic
hdfs.url=hdfs://10.15.167.119:8020
flush.size=3
locale=en-us
timezone=UTC
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
hive.metastore.uris=thrift://10.15.167.119:9083
hive.integration=true
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD
```

I am able to save data into HDFS if I remove hive integration and format.class from hdfs quickstart-hdfs.properties.
When hive integration is enabled I receive following exception stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaProjectorException: Schema version required for BACKWARD compatibility
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:401)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.write(DataWriter.java:374)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.put(HdfsSinkTask.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to deserialize byte stream received from Kafka topic and save it in hive??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Avro with the Schema Registry for your messages, you should be using `AvroConverter` not `ByteArrayConverter`, i.e.:

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use avroconverter I get following exception Error deserializing Avro message for id -1  Unknown magic byte!".

Comment: How’s the data being produced? If it’s Avro that’s been serialised with the Confluent Schema Registry serialiser (eg with Kafka Connect source) then it works fine.

Comment: Data is not serialized with Confluent schema registry serialization techniques. It has been serialized with org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer. Is there any limitation in Kafka connect the way data has to be serialized??

Comment: If you want to use the schema registry (eg you are specifying schema.compatibility) then you need to use the Confluent avro serialiser, yes.

Comment: Sorry for deviating the topic. In flume hdfs sink we can use interceptors to attach the schema to incoming data and using kite dataset, data can be managed in hive (Ex:- https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite-examples/blob/master/json/README.md). This kind of functionality can be achieved by kafka connect?? I do not have control on incoming data to produce data with confluent schema registry. I need to find a way to persist incoming byte array serialized data into hive and hdfs.

Comment: Attaching the link to know the way of data being produced https://github.com/fearofcode/avro-byte-array-serialization/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wkh/learningavro/UserSerDe.java

Answer (score 1):

I went through your comments and your code.
You are using ByteArrayOutputStream to encode and this type of data cannot be understood by kafka-connect. Instead use the below way of sending the data.

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
          io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
          io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
```

And when sending the data use this,

```
 GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(User.getClassSchema());
 record.put("favorite_color", user.getFavoriteColor());
 record.put("favorite_number", user.getFavoriteNumber());
 record.put("name", user.getName());
 ProducerRecord<Object, Object> precord = new ProducerRecord<>("topic1",record);
 producer.send(precord);
```

In your kafka connect configurations use:

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

Comment: Using Confluent Avro Converters I was able to transfer data and save in both hive and hdfs. I was looking for a way to deserialize byte array using the schema available in schema registry.

Comment: If you are using io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter to deserialize in your kafka connect then you cant send using byte array.
That is because the AvroConverter doesn't act like a normal avro desrializer instead it looks for a version data (This is a metadata put when AvroConverter is used while serializing). It adds this version to do a look up using this version to the schema registry to get the entire schema. Also serializing like this saves a lot of data over the network as sending schema with every record is not required only the version is sent.